# Keep DOCPROPERTY in a single line

Tags: vba, properties, ms-word

My task is to keep a 'custom document property' in a single line.
Opening a docProperty's 'field code' (using Shift + F9) shows the following line:

```
{DOCPROPERTY "SYSTEM NAME" \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

How can I style the specific property?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "formatting property" in Word that will force content to stay in a single line. There is, however, a field code that will keep the content on a single line: the `MacroButton` field. You can next the `DocProperty` field in the `MacroButton` field to force the content to a single line:

```
{ MacroButton NoMacro { DocProperty "SYSTEM NAME" } }
```

Just write in the any macro name that does NOT exist in your environment so that clicking the field doesn't cause anything to happen.

Note: There is no switch named "* MEGAFORMAT", although there is one named * MergeFormat. But you shouldn't use that as it can cause really odd formatting problems. You can use * CharFormat, however.

Comment: Currently I see a default message "DisplayText cannot span more than one line!" - is it possible to replace it with a custom string?

Comment: No, that's built-in. And an IF field doesn't "see" the message, only the content, so you can't use that to figure it out, either. How is the custom document property being generated? Maybe you need to shorten that up, or split it into more than one property...

Answer (score 1):

Use non-breaking spaces between the words in the actual document property; there's nothing you can do to achieve that in the DOCPROPERTY field.

Comment: Isn't there a way in VBA to find out when it happens and change the style?

Comment: There is no Style definition that will force content to stay on one line, either.